# If the only thing I use MySQL for is Wordpress, do I need MySQL's timezone tables?

Tags: admin, mysql

The only thing I have MySQL around for is Wordpress.  Some MySQL features, I gather, require you to import the system timezone database into special tables in the `mysql` database.  (Which seems like a silly way to do things, but never mind.)  Does Wordpress make use of any of those features?

The MySQL global time zone is set to 'SYSTEM', and the server runs in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress only uses the tables it creates upon installation. Technically WP wouldn't have a problem with removing tables that are not in the created tables. However, messing with the tables in the `mysql` database is not necessarily the best for MySQL itself. Also, if you are trying to optimize MySQL by removing tables and databases, you might want to look at alternative data storage.

Comment: The MySQL documentation makes it sound like various time-related SQL functions use these tables implicitly, but perhaps *only* if you set the database timezone to something other than 'SYSTEM'.  The question is really 'what are Wordpress's expectations of MySQL regarding time stamps'?  Also, what alternative data storage options exist?  (I would be _delighted_ to get rid of MySQL, but my options on this particular hosting provider are MySQL and 'anything PHP can do using flat files and no cron jobs'.)

Comment: I believe wordpress sets the PHP timezone to UTC and saves all timestamps in UTC as well.